# Trying to converte lasagne.layers.SliceLayer(input_from_previous_layer, -1, 1) fom theano to keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, theano, keras-layer

I am rewriting a neural network model in Keras which is already written in theano.
I am not able to convert following code/line in Keras as there is no SliceLayer in Keras

```
lasagne.layers.SliceLayer(input_from_previous_layer, -1, 1)
```

Comment: So your question is what the equivalent Keras code would be for this snippet?

Comment: Thanks @Mike for your time and Yes, I am looking for equivalent Keras code for this snippet. and sorry for the late reply

Comment: Have you got any solution for this